# 1366 SQL STATE 22007 Invalid DateTime Format

Tags: php, sql

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect double value: 'All Age' for column `unistudioflix_uni`.`movies`.`rating` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `movies` (`title`, `slug`, `maturity_rating`, `featured`, `password`, `keyword`, `description`, `tmdb`, `trailer_url`, `director_id`, `actor_id`, `genre_id`, `duration`, `publish_year`, `rating`, `released`, `detail`, `is_protect`, `a_language`, `created_by`, `status`, `series`, `subtitle`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Bahubali : The Beggining, bhubali, all age, 1, ?, {"en":null}, {"en":null}, N, not avaiable, 1, 1, 1, 230, 2015, All Age, 26-07-2019, {"en":"The first of two cinematic parts, the film follows Shivudu / Shiva, an adventurous young man who helps his love Avanthika rescue Devasena, the former queen of Mahishmati who is now a prisoner under the tyrannical rule of king Bhallaladeva. The story concludes in"}, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2021-03-27 11:59:28, 2021-03-27 11:59:28))

Comment: You didn't include the actual PHP code which is generating this insert, but in any case, the string and date literals need to be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Can you let me more data about your sql table?

Answer (score 0):

To solve the invalid datetime format, use the YYYYMMDD for unambiguous date determination. Please note that using `''` is recommended for date values.

> '20210327 11:59:28 AM', '20210327 11:59:28 AM'

If you would like to use `dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss xm` format, then you need to use CONVERT function with the specific style.

> convert(datetime,'27-03-21 11:59:28 AM',5)

Note that `5` is just an argument, sometimes addressed as style ; no need to worried about it.

Let me know if it works.